# Tennis courts inside or near Kruger National Park

Tags: south-africa, national-parks, activities, sport, kruger-national-park

I know there is a [golf course](http://www.sanparks.org/parks/kruger/tourism/activities/golf_course.php) inside Kruger National Park (South Africa), but does anyone know if there is anywhere to play tennis either inside the park or nearby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it personally pains me that someone would play golf or tennis while there are animals to be searched for outside the camp, in arguably the top game reserve in the world, I realise it's each to their own :)

Skukuza, the biggest camp inside the park is also the most 'touristy'.  And yes, the [Protea Hotel Kruger Gate](http://www.wotif.com/hotel/View?hotel=W280476&) there has not only a tennis court, but a heated outdoor pool.

Address:

> Protea Hotel Kruger Gate
>
> Portia Shabangu Road
>
> Skukuza 1350
>
> Mpumalanga
>
> South Africa